# Android - Can't Click on Button

Tags: android, button, onclick, visibility, invisible

I have a button that is declared "gone" in the XML file:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Therefore, by default the button is hidden.  The button will become visible depending on another condition in the .java by the following line.:

```
smsexplain.setVisibility(0);
```

I have set up a proper `onClickListener` for the button via:

```
Button edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edithookup_req);
        edit.setVisibility(0);
        edit.setOnClickListener(onEdit);
```

The problem arises in runtime. The button shows up like it is suppose to; however, the button cannot be touched.  The only way to set off the `onClickListener` is to use the D-pad or scroll-ball on the physical phone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show the full XML declaration for the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `setVisibility()` with a `0`.

Try using the correct variable from the `View` class. For example: `View.VISIBLE`.